# Join Domain controller hosted in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to join a Domain hosted in Google VM from my local computer ?
I have created an win server 2012 and configured AD and DNS in my GCP but I am unable to join that domain from my win 10 laptop.

[image]

I have tried to change the DNS settings of my pc and tried to ping the domain name but I can't , but I can ping the domain ip address. After reverting back the changes in dns settings and making it dynamic I am unable to ping the ip address too !
If I create other servers in my GCP I think I can join to my domain because their internal ip is in sequence.

Comment: In order to get this to work, first, you need to correctly setup DNS and open the required ports. Unless you are using a VPN this is very dangerous. Never expose Active Directory to the public Internet. Using DNS root names such as `local` are not publicly resolvable, therefore your clients must use the Active Directory DNS server for name resolution or hardcode values in your local `/etc/hosts` (which I do not recommend).

Comment: Please provide more information , is this your private or public domain ? . If this is your private DNS server you might need to create outbound policy and allow it through VPN and if it is public DNS then it could be something wrong with your Configuration .

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If yes, could you please describe?